# mysql load data in file import zero's with decimal data with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, null

I'm running into a problem with loading csv data of multiple files to mysql.
When importing the csv seperate (one at a time) via phpmyadmin, the data is showing correctly with decimal values.

But when importing all the columns contain 0.00 in case of the values from the csv file.

This is the PHP im using:

```
// to create the headers
foreach($csvtable as $file){
    
    $table = basename($file, '.csv'); 

    mysqli_query($conn, "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$csvtable."(
    `colum1` decimal(6,2),
    `colum2` decimal(6,2),
    `colum3` decimal(6,2),
    `colum4` decimal(5,2),
    `colum5` decimal(6,2),
    `colum6` decimal(6,2),
    `colum7` decimal(5,2),
    `colum8` decimal(6,2),
    `colum9` decimal(6,2),
    `colum10` decimal(5,2) 
    )
    ");
// Code to load the data from the files in the tables and ignore the header

mysqli_query($conn, "
    LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE ".$table."
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    ");
```

The following is in the csv file:

```
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10
4.50;1.67;0.00;0.00;0.83;0.00;0.00;0.83;0.00;0.00
9.00;3.33;0.00;0.00;1.75;0.00;0.00;1.75;0.00;0.00
13.50;5.00;0.00;0.00;2.58;0.00;0.00;2.58;0.00;0.00
18.00;6.67;0.00;0.00;3.50;0.00;0.00;3.50;0.00;0.00
22.50;8.33;0.00;0.00;4.33;0.00;0.00;4.33;0.00;0.00
27.00;10.08;0.00;0.00;5.25;0.00;0.00;5.25;0.00;0.00
31.50;11.75;0.00;0.00;6.08;0.00;0.00;6.08;0.00;0.00
36.00;13.42;0.00;0.00;7.00;0.00;0.00;7.00;0.00;0.00
40.50;15.08;0.00;0.00;7.83;0.00;0.00;7.83;0.00;0.00
45.00;16.75;0.00;0.00;8.75;0.00;0.00;8.75;0.00;0.00
49.50;18.42;0.00;0.00;9.58;0.00;0.00;9.58;0.00;0.00
```

But loads like:

```
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00
```

The tables are made with the exact structure like i am importing it by phpmyadmin itself.
What am i forgetting here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete! But I change a little and write it in my side and worked properly. In first step you used group name for crate table but insert it in another table. Use same name for `create table` and `inset into`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","test");

echo '<br/>';


    $file = "D:\\a.csv";
    
    $table = basename($file, '.csv');
    
    echo '----------'.$table.'</br>';
    
    mysqli_query($con, "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$table."(
    `colum1` decimal(6,2),
    `colum2` decimal(6,2),
    `colum3` decimal(6,2),
    `colum4` decimal(5,2),
    `colum5` decimal(6,2),
    `colum6` decimal(6,2),
    `colum7` decimal(5,2),
    `colum8` decimal(6,2),
    `colum9` decimal(6,2),
    `colum10` decimal(5,2)
    )
    ");
    // Code to load the data from the files in the tables and ignore the header
    
    mysqli_query($con, "
    LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE ".$table."
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    ");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hajibaba, i minimized my code. I forgot to mention that when i change the decimal to varchar i dont have any problem with importing in the right table. The next problem then is to sort a table on number. I dont have the sorting problem when the colums are set to decimal.

Comment: using decimal is good and no need to change it to varchar. Use decimal and order by to do your desired.

Comment: I did not changed it to varchar, but tested it before setting it on decimal with the varchar type. The importing of the multiple files goes correctly. Every file needs to make its own table.